# Condition for differentiability I’d limit function

Tags: analysis

I’ve read in my notes, a typical way to show that the limit of a sequence of differentiable functions is differentiable, is to show that the sequence derivatives converges uniformly and that the functions converge point-wise at some point.

Is it not sufficient to show that the sequence of differentiable functions converges uniformly? Note that this is a weaker condition that is implied by the condition stated in the first paragraph.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Come again? The uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

By Weierstrass Theorem we can approximate $f(x)=|x|$ uniformly by polynomials in $[-1,1]$. Polynomials are differentiable but $f$ is not.